# Set a mark to its previous value

Tags: mark

Sometimes I use marks to navigate easily through different files using `mA`, `mB`... and `'A`, `'B`...

And sometime (more often than I'd like to admit) because of inattention or whatever the reason is, I use `m[LETTER]` with an already existing mark which erase its previous value when I don't want to. Most of the time when I do that I don't have open the file originally pointed by the mark.

In this case when I immedialy realized that I made a mistake, is it possible to get the previous value of my mark other than remembering where it was pointing to, navigating to this location and setting it again?

I haven't found a command like that in the doc so if that doesn't exist is there a clever workaround that some of you use in this situation?

Comment: Also you could look at this post for further informations : http://superuser.com/questions/687441/how-to-undo-accidental-mark-overwrite-instead-of-jumping-in-vim

Comment: @Nobe4 thanks for your link I hadn't found it but it seems to confirm that it isn't really possible to do that easily.

Comment: Use the jump commands (`ctrl-o`, `ctrl-i` and `:jumps`) with your own personal memory :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is some basic VimScript which roughly does what you want.

We override the `ma` through `mz` mappings to store the current value in `g:previous_marks` before calling the original `m` to actually set the mark. We also define `<Leader>ma` through `<Leader>mz` to show the history for said mark.

You will probably want to store the info in `g:previous_marks` in a more organized way, and add the ability to quickly restore a mark (rather than just  seeing the locations), but this example shows how it can be done, further tweaks are left as an exercise to the reader ;-)

```
let g:previous_marks = {}
fun! MyMark(mark)
    let l:marks = ''
    redir => l:marks
        try
            silent! execute 'marks ' . a:mark
        catch
        endtry
    redir END

    if l:marks != ''
        if !has_key(g:previous_marks, a:mark)
            let g:previous_marks[a:mark] = []
        endif
        call add(g:previous_marks[a:mark], split(l:marks, "\n")[1])
    endif

    execute 'normal! m' . a:mark
endfun

fun! ShowHistory(mark)
    if !has_key(g:previous_marks, a:mark)
        echoerr 'No history for ' . a:mark
        return
    endif

    for l:line in g:previous_marks[a:mark]
        echo l:line
    endfor
endfun

fun! MakeMappings()
    for l:char in range(97, 122)
        let l:char = nr2char(l:char)

        execute 'nnoremap <silent> m' . l:char . ' :call MyMark("' . l:char . '")<CR>'
        execute 'nnoremap <silent> <Leader>m' . l:char . ' :call ShowHistory("' . l:char . '")<CR>'
    endfor
endfun

call MakeMappings()
```

Comment: Wow as usual amazing answer! I'll try take time this weekend to implement the exercice for the reader ;)

Answer (score 2):

Since the actual problem seems to be navigation between multiple files/positions, I'd suggest this simple solution, which is based on the [Unite](https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim) plugin:

```
:Unite jump -auto-preview
```

This command (which can be mapped to something like `<leader>j` for example) will show the jump list, *with* a preview: each time you navigate the list with `j`/`k`, several lines around the cursor position in that file will be displayed.

[image]

---

### Alternative:

The default marks are so easy to be overwritten: perhaps *named* bookmarks would better fit your use case, e.g. with the [simple_bookmarks](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/simple_bookmarks.vim) plugin.

Comment: I can't really say that the problem is this type of navigation because I use those marks really occasionnaly and most of the time I navigate differently through my files. Nevertheless I've been thinking for a long time that I should use the jump list more often so that seems like a nice way to do it!

Comment: Even if they can be saved between vim sessions, it's too easy to overwrite marks. I added an alternative solution.

Comment: Indeed your alternative solution seems to be worth a try thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what you want, but perhaps more useful: the [signature](https://github.com/kshenoy/vim-signature) plugin.  It shows the current marks as signs in the gutter margin, and has simple shortcuts for editing them.  It can also put the list of signs in a location list for quick access.

Comment: I'm not a great fan of the visible mark on the margin but it seems to have some interesting features I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @statox In the same vein, there's also [showmarks](https://github.com/zakj/vim-showmarks).  It shows literally _all_ marks (the plugin above only deals with alphabetic ones), and can be toggled with a key.  I find it useful occasionally.

Comment: Yes I've been using showmarks for a few time (unlike signature) that's why I said I'm not a fan of marks in the margin but I'm trying signature right now to see if I like it :-)