# why can't I map <Space> to <C>?

Tags: key-bindings, vimrc

I found that it's really hard for me to hit <kbd>Control</kbd> and other keys simultaneously, and I discovered that the <kbd>space</kbd> key is rarely used, so I decided to map it to <kbd>Control</kbd> . Thus, when I want to hit <kbd>Control</kbd>+ <kbd>f</kbd> for scrolling, I can instead hit <kbd>space</kbd>+ <kbd>f</kbd>, which would be a lot easier.
But with this line

```
nnoremap <Space> <C>
```

nothing change.

How can I do that? Is it possible?

By the way, is it a good practice to map <kbd>Space</kbd>  to <kbd>Control</kbd>  ?

Comment: `<CR>` is Enter, not  Control ... and I think you will need to remap Ctrl to Space at OS level.

Comment: oh…i think i mistake one for another

Comment: @VanLaser But,even when I change the <CR> to <C>, it still doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Because ctrl key by itself cannot be mapped in vim.  It has to be in conjunction with another letter eg. `<C-e>`.  You will have to remap it at OS level, like @VanLaser said.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately I think that the comment of EvergreenTree is right: you can't map <kbd>ctrl</kbd> as a single key into vim.

Also I tried to get what you want using the `langmap` option which allows to substitute a key with another one in normal mode. I thought something like `set langmap +=\ ^` could have worked but it doesn't (with that, <kbd>Space</kbd> get your cursor at the beginning of the line).

So  the best I could suggest to you is to add the following lines to your `.vimrc`:

```
function! RemapSpaceToCtrl()
    for l:char in range(97, 122)
        let l:char = nr2char(l:char)

        execute 'nnoremap <silent> <Space>' . l:char . ' <C-' . l:char . '><CR>'
    endfor
endfunction

call RemapSpaceToCtrl()
```

The function maps `<Space>X` to `<C-X>` where `X` is all the letters of the alphabet. This way <kbd>Space</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> increments a number, <kbd>Space</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> goes down one page etc...

That's probably not the cleanest solution and you might want to improve it but that could be a workaround.

*To render unto Caesar the things which are Caesar's I get inspiration to map a prefix followed by different letters to another prefix followed by the letters from a function written by CarpetSmoker [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/4032/1841)*